# Binning duration in time periods using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

For the study I'm performing I need to know bin the "duration" of a job into arbitrary periods (hourly, daily, monthly, etc.). If the job 1 started 9:30 and ended 12:30, I would like to have in these 4 periods (9-10, 10-11, 11-12, 12-13) a consumption like : 30 minutes, 1 hour, 1 hour and 30 minutes.

I could make this work, but it is extremely slow. A base case with a ~30000 jobs takes about 100 seconds and it represents only 0.5% of the total.

The frame is built like this:

#### Start

```
import pandas as pd
frequency = "1H"
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "job" : 1,
            "start" : pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01 10:00:00"),
            "end" : pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01 11:33:00"),
        },
        {
            "job" : 2,
            "start" : pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01 10:00:00"),
            "end" : pd.to_datetime("2020-01-02 09:33:00"),
        }
    ]
)

base_frame = df.set_index("job", append = True).stack().reset_index(level=[1,2])
base_frame = base_frame.drop("level_2", axis = 1).rename(columns={0 : 'time'})
```

#### Base frame

The base frame basically creates an id and puts both "start" and "end" in the same column.

```
|id  |   job | time                |
|---:|------:|:--------------------|
|  0 |     1 | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 |
|  0 |     1 | 2020-01-01 11:33:00 |
|  1 |     2 | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 |
|  1 |     2 | 2020-01-02 09:33:00 |
```

#### The super slow part

Ok here is where the problem starts for real. For each group id (it could be job id too), I need to resample, thus putting the "time" column in the index. Then I need to back fill my data. Finally I calculate the duration for each group.

In the end using "where", I limit the size of the periods.

Doing stuff like this is already an improvement, because using for loop on the groupby took the double of the time.

```
def assignFunc(x):
    x["duration"] = pd.Timedelta(0)
    
    if len(x) >= 2:
        x.iloc[0, x.columns.get_loc('duration')] = x.index[1] - x['time'].iloc[0]
        x.iloc[1:, x.columns.get_loc('duration')] = x['time'].iloc[1:] - x.index[1:]  
        
    else:
        x.iloc[0, x.columns.get_loc('duration')] = base_frame['time'].iloc[-1] - base_frame['time'].iloc[0]

    return x["duration"]

frame = base_frame.groupby(base_frame.index).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('time', drop=False).resample(frequency).bfill().assign(duration=assignFunc))
frame["duration"] = frame.where(frame.duration <= pd.Timedelta(frequency), pd.Timedelta(frequency))["duration"]
print(frame.drop("time",axis=1))
```

#### Result

```
  time                                    
0 2020-01-01 10:00:00    1 0 days 01:00:00
  2020-01-01 11:00:00    1 0 days 00:33:00
1 2020-01-01 10:00:00    2 0 days 01:00:00
  2020-01-01 11:00:00    2 0 days 01:00:00
  2020-01-01 12:00:00    2 0 days 01:00:00
  2020-01-01 13:00:00    2 0 days 01:00:00
  2020-01-01 14:00:00    2 0 days 01:00:00
  2020-01-01 15:00:00    2 0 days 01:00:00
  2020-01-01 16:00:00    2 0 days 01:00:00
....
```

Do you have any idea how to approach this problem? The ideas I have rely on for-loops (because for each one I need to resample) that would be super slow.

Thank you all in advance!